# Travis CI - failing to deploy to Firebase - Cannot find module 'ipaddr.js'

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, travis-ci, firebase-tools

I added [.travis.yml](https://github.com/bob-lee/react-joanne/blob/master/.travis.yml) to my project and each time I commit to `master` branch, it runs all tests / scripts ok but last `firebase deploy` fails consistently with [error](https://travis-ci.org/bob-lee/react-joanne) like below:

[image]

But certainly I am installing dependencies under `functions` folder and can deploy on localhost with no problem.

My `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 6
branches:
  only:
    - master
install:
  - yarn
  - CI=false yarn build:ssr
  - yarn fns:deps
after_success:
  - node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --non-interactive --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --project react-joanne
deploy:
  provider: firebase
  skip_cleanup: true
  token:
    secure: "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
  project: "react-joanne"
```